# Cannot decrypt encrypted file in android lollipop

Tags: android, encryption, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an encrypt/decrypt mechanism for downloaded files in my app.

This mechanism works in all android devices and versions prior to android 5.0-lollipop.

Here is decryption process:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, cipher);
byte[] fileByte = new byte[(int) file.length()];
int j = cipherInputStream.read(fileByte);
return fileByte;
```

cipher and key were generated before and are used in whole app:

```
 key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
 try {
     cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

When I decrypt a file with about 200,000 bytes in android 5.0, j (variable before return) is about 8000 which is much lower than 200000, while in older android versions it is exactly equal to decrypted file length.

I found that the problem is in decryption. Because I can encrypt a file in android 5.0 and decrypt it in older android versions, but not vice versa. However I am posting encryption process:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AESutil.key);
cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(output, cipher);
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    cipherOutputStream.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your stream handling seems pretty funky to me. Creating a buffer of the size of the file does not mean that all those bytes are actually read. And you do not seem to explicitly close the stream during encryption (but maybe that's just not included).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead Yes I have closed them. The problem still exists.

Comment: Could you make sure that the right amount of bytes are also read, by reading bytes until `j` is `-1`?

Comment: Usually the problem is not the decryption but the key generation. Therefore I strongly recommend comparing the used keys before encrypting/decrypting.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead. I changed the code as you said and the problem get solved. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Cipher example (L) :

APPPATH is String to my aplication directory on sd card

```
static void encrypt(File file, String pass) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(APPPATH+"/E_"+file.getName());


        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(pass.getBytes(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);

        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }

        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();


    }



     static void decrypt(File file, String pass) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(APPPATH+"/D_"+file.getName());
            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(pass.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
            int b;
            byte[] d = new byte[8];
            while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
                fos.write(d, 0, b);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            cis.close();
        }
```